# Azure WebJob Publishing: Last in Wins

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines

So I have recently setup automated deployment for my **WebAPI** that also has **FIVE** **webjobs**.

But the problem is that I deploy the web jobs as **FIVE** distinct build steps within the **VSO** build definition and after the deployment is successful I don't have **FIVE** **webjobs** deployed. I only have **ONE webjob** deployed, **the last one**.

This makes me think that when doing the **Azure Web App Deployment Build** Step, everything is getting erased **before the zip package is deployed**.

---

### Question

Does anybody know how can I make it so that deploying the web job does NOT erase the previous web jobs (that are in different folders anyway)?

Comment: You can check [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) for web job deploying.

Comment: That depends on what technique you are using to deploy the WebJobs. If you are using WebDeploy, and you set it to delete unknown files at destination, then it would behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Apparently there is a "Do not delete" flag on the Azure Deployment step. Checking this and making sure you SAVE (this is still a little awkward in VSO) solves this problem.